TIA Toolbox - Custom Model Integration
I have been using Tia Toolbox, to integrate with my custom model. Is there someone to help me integrating my custom model in tia toolbox?
This is the original code using a pretrained model.
# Importing a pretrained PyTorch model from TIAToolbox
predictor = PatchPredictor(pretrained_model='resnet18-kather100k', batch_size=32)

# Users can load any PyTorch model architecture instead using the following script
model = vanilla.CNNModel(backbone="resnet18", num_classes=9) # Importing model from torchvision.models.resnet18
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(weights_path, map_location="cpu"), strict=True)

def preproc_func(img):
    img = PIL.Image.fromarray(img)
    img = transforms.ToTensor()(img)
    return img.permute(1, 2, 0)

model.preproc_func = preproc_func
predictor = PatchPredictor(model=model, batch_size=32)

I need to integrate my own model, not a pretrained one. For example, I've trained an EfficientNet-B0 model and saved the best weights. I want to use my custom model and load my saved weights instead of using a pretrained model.

In the example you have provided there is a weights_path which is used to load the weights of a trained model once the base (pretrained) model has been loaded. You should be able to just replace the base model (if needed) and the path to the new weights to integrate your own model
